# Cannot get App Store purchase because Apple ID required but I'm already logged in

Tags: apple-id, mac-appstore

I'm already logged in on my Mac with my Apple ID. When the App Store asks for my Apple ID before getting a new app, I enter it correctly and have no wrong password errors.

The odd thing, is that when the App Store asks for my login, it auto-fills the email of a family member who has a secondary profile on this computer.

However, instead of getting the app, it just shows this alert which has no place to "enter them here" as it requests:

[image: sign in required]

If I click "Get" it just shows the notification popup over and over for three times then the process stops.

What's wrong with my App Store connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked down in the right corner of the App Store while in my profile and I saw my family member's name, so it would appear they used my profile to connect to the App Store using their Apple ID while logged in under my profile.

My App Store user was hidden for some reason, so I went to **Store** > **Sign Out** menu to log them out of the App Store and now I can download my apps.

Strange that Apple doesn't provide an option to switch between profiles and only shows a broken dialog with no explanation when you login with your own Apple ID.

Comment: Signing out and back in is the very first thing to do!

Comment: That's what I thought I was doing when it asked me for my Apple ID and password when I tried to get the app. Instead of signing me in under my user, it was stuck on my family member's user despite my sign in being completely different.